# Azure Blob storage images not loading in Safari browser

Tags: azure, safari, mobile-safari, azure-blob-storage

I'm using Azure Blob Storage for storing images and when I'm trying to access them, they are working in Chrome but not in Safari.
Does anyone have any idea about it?

Comment: Can you share the link of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My image format is WebP which is not supported in Safari.